# postgres PANI[0000] connect failed: pq: role "root" does not exist pid=13863, postgres v 9.5 - Horizon

Tags: horizon, postgres

Getting below error when trying to connect to postgres  (trying to start Horizon)

**PANI[0000] connect failed: pq: role "root" does not exist  pid=13863
panic: (*logrus.Entry) (0xbcb320,0xc4200112c0)**

db-url="postgresql://user_name:pwd@localhost/db_name"

Owner of db is the given user. Have checked the conf file. It is correct.

If I use the user & password (used in url) from command prompt, I can login. But not via code.